# How can you tell if a RDBMS is an ArcSDE Geodatabase?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, query

I want to know if there is any way I can query the *RDBMS* to determine whether it is an *ArcSDE Geodatabase*, or if I have to do it through *ArcObjects*. I am wondering if it would be enough to check if the `SDE` schema exists on the target database, and then maybe check if the `SDE.VERSION` table also exists and then conclude that it's an *ArcSDE Geodatabase*.

The *ArcSDE Geodatabases* are `Oracle`, and I use `ArcObjects SDK 10 .NET` in `C#`.

Comment: I'm not proposing this [**previous question**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17373/how-to-determine-storage-type-st-geom-oracle-from-arcpy-python) as a duplicate but I think it has some elements in common with your question and so may be worth you reviewing

Comment: @PolyGeo I didn't make it clear in my question that I use Oracle and the .NET SDK, so naturally I would like a solution on either of these "platforms". I am writing RDBMS because if i went through ArcObjects what the underlying database type is wouldn't matter. But in cases where I had to query the RDBMS directly, i would prefer an Oracle query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcGIS 10.0 can connect directly to a database.  Although, the connection properties that you provide to the SdeWorksapceFactory are slightly different.  You could just try to connect to the database as a geodatabase.  You should get an error if it isn't a geodatabase.  If you have a workspace reference already, you can test the workspace to see if it is an ISqlWorkspace (database) or an IVersionedWorkspace (geodatabase).

```
if (myWorkspace is IVersionedWorkspace)
{
     //geodatabase
}
else if (myWorkspace is ISqlWorkspace)
{
     //database
}
else 
{
     //something else like shapefile, personal or file gdb...
}
```

At 10.1, the connection properties are the same, so it is a little simpler.  All you have to do then is connect to the database/geodatabase and query the [workspace properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002z7000000).

You could check for the sde schema (and posibly the dbo schema on SQLServer), and then check for the SDE.Version (or dbo.SDE_Version) table.  That will tell if there is a geodatabase.  Obviously this is fairly rudimentary, and only tells you if you have a geodatabase.  Nothing about your ability to connect to it.  For example, the geodatabase may not be accepting connections, or it may be corrupt.

Comment: good points in the end there, I also got a tip about checking the table `SDE.SERVER_CONFIG` where a **status** attribute is either `1 = ok || 2 = gdb is paused or inactive.`